# How do I parse a MySQL date string where the month doesn't have a leading zero?

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

How do I convert strings like `'1021970'` (January 2, 1970) or `'12021970'` (December 2, 1970) with varying month lengths into MySQL dates?

Comment: You read the manual for `STR_TO_DATE`

Comment: AND lpad https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

Answer (score 0):

In a string where the month doesn't have a leading zero (i.e. sometimes it has one digit, sometimes it has two digits), the day always has a leading zero, and the year is always four digits:

```sql
SELECT
    IF(
        LENGTH(`your_date_column`) = 7,
        STR_TO_DATE(INSERT(`your_date_column`, 1, 0, '0'), '%m%d%Y'),
        STR_TO_DATE(`your_date_column`, '%m%d%Y')
    );
```

To test:

```sql
-- January 2, 1970.
SELECT
    IF(
        LENGTH('1021970') = 7,
        STR_TO_DATE(INSERT('1021970', 1, 0, '0'), '%m%d%Y'),
        STR_TO_DATE('1021970', '%m%d%Y')
    );
```

```sql
-- December 2, 1970.
SELECT
    IF(
        LENGTH('12021970') = 7,
        STR_TO_DATE(INSERT('12021970', 1, 0, '0'), '%m%d%Y'),
        STR_TO_DATE('12021970', '%m%d%Y')
    );
```